# Mongo aggregation - how to wrap expression value with some function?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is a statement what just compares equality *kilm* field value (of a_object) with *my_b* field value (of b_object):

```
db.a_object.aggregate([{
$match: {
}
}, {
  $lookup: {
        "from": "b_object",
        let: {
            idid: "$kilm"
        },
        pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {"$eq": ["$$idid", "$my_b"]}}}],
        "as": "bs_objects"
}
}])
```

But I want to make it wrapping *kilm* value (or *my_b* value) with some function, for instance build-in `hex_md5()`

I.e. I want some like this:

```
db.a_object.aggregate([{
$match: {
}
}, {
  $lookup: {
        "from": "b_object",
        let: {
            idid: "$kilm"
        },
        pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {"$eq": ["hex_md5($$idid)", "$my_b"]}}}],
        "as": "bs_objects"
}
}])
```

But it doesn't work.

YES, I want to hash kilm field value when checking equality, NOT "kilm" string (field name).
That's because this way:

```
    pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {"$eq": [hex_md5("$$idid"), "$my_b"]}}}],
```

is NOT for me.

Does Mongo provide some feature which could provide such behaviour? If yes, how to do it?